# GWT dygraph not showing(collapses on top left corner)

Tags: gwt, resize, google-visualization, dygraphs

I am trying to create a dygraph(using gviz) in a GWT application. The dygraph shows up as collapsed chart on the top left corner. i can see the slider in that corner.
If i resize the browser window, the chart shows up as expected.

I thought of calling chart.resize(width,height) but get an error chart has no method resize.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use GViz, you're most likely using a wrapper, not the real dygraph object.

Does "chart.date_graph.resize(width, height)" work for you?